# <cfmail> failing when <cfmailparam> attaches image over https

Tags: coldfusion

I  think this is more of a server setup issue?

As the subject says, when I "embed" images to a cfmail, using cfmailparam, if the image is called over http**s**, the email fails. The error I get in mail.log is

> javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Any ideas? 
Thx!

Comment: What is your ColdFusion version?

Comment: It's ColdFusion 11

Answer (score 1):

Check the {cf_root}/logs/exception.log to see if there is anything more informative.

Sounds like CF isn't liking the SSL certificate. I know some CF versions and using CFHTTP, etc. don't like wildcard or SAN certificates and you have to import those to the keystore.

You have to grab the certificate then use the keytool to import it. This will require a CF restart after.

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore ./cacerts -alias myCert -file myCert.cer`

Adobe has a write up on how-to: [How to import certificates to ColdFusion's truststore](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will coordinate with the hosting guys, let you know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be because your Java version which is running ColdFusion is not supporting new TLS versions. You can solve this by upgrading Java to 1.8 or later or you can add the following to the JVM config in the ColdFusion Administrator.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```